# Xamarin Popup : Object reference not set to an instance of an object using Rg.Plugins.Popup

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, popup

I am using Rg.Plugins.popup to display popups In my Xamarin app.

```cs
async void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{   
    var model = new DatePopup();       
    await Navigation.PushPopupAsync(model, false);
}
```

This is the code I am using to display the popup.

```xml
<pages:PopupPage HasSystemPadding="false" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup" xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" x:Class="ATTG.GT.Mobile.Native.Views.DatePopup">
    <pages:PopupPage.Animation>
        <animations:ScaleAnimation PositionIn="Center" PositionOut="Center" ScaleIn="1.2" ScaleOut="0.8" DurationIn="400" DurationOut="300" EasingIn="SinOut" EasingOut="SinIn" HasBackgroundAnimation="True" />
    </pages:PopupPage.Animation>
    <pages:PopupPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Button Text="OK"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </pages:PopupPage.Content>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

This is my popup page. When I try to display the popup I am getting an  Object reference not set to an instance of an object exception. When I checked the object I found that systemPadding property is giving the exception. Anyone has any fix for this exception? I am adding an image of the exception[image: Error]

Comment: your given code snippet is looks like right. There is no padding property in your code. I can help help you if you put your whole Xaml code here.

Comment: My whole xaml popup code is here. Where should I add the padding property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to install Rg.Plugin.Popup reference on both IOS and Droid project on your xamarin.forms project, then re-run your project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try.

```
 await Navigation.PushAsync(model, true);
```